# grep a block of text delimited by two key lines

Tags: grep, match, textblock

I have a text file that contains text blocks roughly formatted like this:

```
Beginning of block
...
...
...
.........some_pattern.......
...
...
End of block

Beginning of block
...
... etc.
```

The blocks can have any number of lines but always start with the two delimiters. What I'd like to do is match "some_pattern" and print the whole block to stdout. With the example above, I would get this only:

```
Beginning of block
...
...
...
.........some_pattern.......
...
...
End of block
```

I've tried with something like this but without success:

```
grep "Beginning of block\n.*some_pattern.*\n.*End of block"
```

Any idea how to do this with grep? (or maybe with some other tool)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -n '/Beginning of block/!b;:a;/End of block/!{$!{N;ba}};{/some_pattern/p}' filename
```

Answer (score 10):

I guess `awk` is better for this:

```
awk '/Beginning of block/ {p=1};
     {if (p==1) {a[NR]=$0}};
     /some_pattern/ {f=1};
     /End of block/ {p=0; if (f==1) {for (i in a) print a[i]};f=0; delete a}' file
```

#### Explanation

It just prints when the `p` flag is "active" and `some_pattern` is matched:

- When it finds `Beginning of block`, then makes variable `p=1` and starts storing the lines in the array `a[]`.
- If it finds `some_pattern`, it sets the flag `f` to 1, so that we know the pattern has been found.
- When it finds `End of block` it resets `p=0`. If `some_pattern` had been found since the last `Beginning of block`, all the lines that had been stored are printed. Finally a[] is cleared and f is reset; we will have a fresh start when we again encounter `Beginning of block`.

#### Other test

```
$ cat a
Beginning of block
blabla
.........some_pattern.......
and here i am
hello
End of block

Beginning of block
...
... etc.
End of block
$ awk '/Beginning of block/ {p=1}; {if(p==1){a[NR]=$0}}; /some_pattern/ {f=1}; /End of block/ {p=0; if (f==1) {for (i in a) print a[i]}; delete a;f=0}' a
Beginning of block
blabla
.........some_pattern.......
and here i am
hello
End of block
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do to retrieve only the block that contains "some_pattern"? I've updated my question to show the output I'm looking for. Any idea?

Comment: Uhms, that's more complicated. For this case you can save the lines in an array, then have a flag for the "some_pattern" and finally print if it exists. I will give it a try in a while.

Comment: @Laurent just updated with proper solution for this requirement.

Comment: @Dining Philosopher thanks a lot for your [edition](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15267898)! Both for the bugfix and improvement of the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I missed something but here is a simpler variation of one of the answers above:

```sh
awk '/Beginning of block/ {p=1}; 
     /End of block/ {p=0; print $0}; 
     {if (p==1) print $0}'
```

You need to print the input line in the `End of Block` case to get both delimiters.

I wanted a slight variation that doesn't print the delimiters. In the OP's question the delimiter pattern is simple and unique. Then the simplest is to pipe into `| grep -v block`. My case was more irregular, so I used the variation below. Notice the `next` statement so the opening block isn't printed by the third statement:

```sh
awk '/Beginning of block/ {p=1; next}; 
     /End of block/ {p=0}; 
     {if (p==1) print $0}'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '/Beginning of block/ { r=""; f=1 } f { r = (r ? r ORS : "") $0 } /End of block/ { if (f && r ~ /some_pattern/) print r; f=0 }' file
```

Results:

```
Beginning of block
...
...
...
.........some_pattern.......
...
...
End of block
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "
/Beginning of block/,/End of block/ {
   N
   /End of block/ { 
      s/some_pattern/&/p
      }
   }"
```

sed is efficient for such a treatment

with grep, you certainly should pass through intermediary file or array.